# Splitting big app into smaller modules - maven

Tags: java, maven, architecture, web-deployment

We are splitting our mammoth project into smaller modules.

Eg: A, B modules in one app and we want to make them independent, compile independently. There are many inter-references.

What's the best way to split dependencies? 
We are looking to currently write an interface and expose it as service for each. AImpl (some classes which need to called by B) and then B uses it by class.forName and typecasts to AImpl. During the runtime, it works.

It needs a lot of rework. Is this right approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would at least consider a straight fork.  This allows your individual projects to evolve independently.  You can clean up bits that they don't use, and if you truly need shared libraries, identify them afterword, and refactor to use them as needed.

I have found in the past that when I've done it this way, I've found that the "dependencies" aren't as common as I thought they were, and that I've shoehorned them into the same shape over the years.

For example, in Module A (let's call it billing) I'll have a customer, which has things like credit terms, outstanding balance, etc.  In Module B (call it support) I'll have the same customer, but they will have totally different attributes, like software versions, or support history.

Other than both being called "User", and having a common ID value they have nothing to do with each other, and don't really belong in the same class.  As soon as Module A forked from Module B, the User objects became much smaller and more focused.

This is the same discovery that people make in micro-services.  The things they thought needed to be shared, did not really need to be shared, and in fact, benefited from decomposing them.  It's not a cure-all, as sometimes there really are complex objects that are truly shared, but it's not as common as you think it is.  Often it's just a matter of two different things having the same "name", and thus being put into the same class/module.

Comment: I am assuming that A and B are not related but they need to be calling each other's functions. Today, they call directly. After fork, what is the best way? B exposes its implementation as an interface and A uses class.forName and type casts it to the implementation interface and uses it.